# Where is URLExistsQ in version 11?

Tags: undocumented, expression-test, internet

Searching this function in the doc,it found nothing.
Is this function be removed?

I want to check weather the url can access from my country.

```
URLExistsQ["http://www.youtubeeeeeeee.com"]
(*in version 11,it returns error*)
```

In version 10,it return false.What about verssion 11?

Comment: `URLExistsQ` is undocumented, but it works for me returning `True` in both V11.0.1 and V10.4.1 (Win7, x64, North America).  What error do you get?

Comment: @WReach try www.youtubeeeeeeeee.com.in version 11,it will return error

Comment: When I try it, I get `URLFetch::invhttp: Couldn't resolve host name.` which is correct since it isn't  a real host name. Remove the extra eee's and it works fine.

Comment: @in the version 10 ,it returns False

Comment: Version 10 here. I get the `URLFetch` error as well, but I don't think that's correct; the function should have returned `False`. (The fact that it doesn't work properly is probably why it's still undocumented.)

Comment: @Taiki maybe we can check status code

Comment: As long as it isn't documented it is impossible to say which behavior is correct/intended. You could argue that an URL with an invalid hostname does not exist, but you could also argue that with an invalid hostname it isn't a valid URL in the first place, so both variants could be considered correct behavior. Only documentation could clarify this. It's a different topic that it often is hard enough to understand the intended behavior for **documented** functions :-)

Comment: Which version are you using?  I tried versions all the way back to 10.0.2 and got the same result in each: issue the message `URLFetch::invhttp` and return `False`.  In any event, you could try `Quiet[URLExistsQ["www.youtubeeeeeeeee.com"], URLFetch::invhttp]`.

Comment: @WReach I remembed there is a doc for ExistsQ.maybe I recall wrongly.Anyway,it.is a method for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Version 11 `URLRead` got added. With that it is simple to define (maybe as a `ResourceFunction`?) `URLExistsQ` by

```
URLExistsQ[url_] := 
 Quiet[URLRead[url, {"StatusCode"}]["StatusCode"] === 200]
```

However, `URLRead` seems to be incredibly slow, in version 12.1 at least, so this is much faster:

```
URLExistsQ[url_String]:=JLink`JavaBlock @ Block[{openConnection, getResponseCode }
    , Needs["JLink`"]
    ; If[Head[JLink`JavaLink[]] =!= LinkObject, JLink`InstallJava[]]
    ; 200 === (JLink`JavaNew["java.net.URL", url] @ openConnection[] ) @ getResponseCode[]
];
```